# What's the state of multi-seat in 10.04 Lucid?

Tags: gdm, nvidia, multiseat

Ubuntu used to support multiseat (that is multiple monitors, multiple keyboards and mice, all hanging off a single computer) pretty well once upon a time. Support wasn't an official feature but gdm and xorg both worked.

These days, gdm doesn't appear support it and while you can downgrade to gdm v2.20, that introduces new issues for me.

Is there any other way to get a viable multiseat system up and running?

Bonus points for anybody who can tell me if it's possible to have twinview working at one of the seats.