# How to set up a multiseat system?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, multiseat

I intent to buy a new Desktop PC, but I'm wondering if I can share one machine between 2 users. I read about the subject, however I didn't find any guide for that, only some isolated answers/comentaries. Then I tried to test it with my laptop that has only one video board, but after some tries that failed and killed my graphicall interface and at each try I had to reinstall my system, I gave up.

I know that LightDM does support multiseat, but it's only unlockable through editing lighdm.conf, there are not any graphicalleasytouseandfullofbuttons programs... and any instructions.

So the questions are:

- Can I have a multiseat system using Ubuntu 11.10/12.04 with two video boards? And if so, HOW?
- Can I have a multiseat using one video board? If so, HOW?

Thank you for the attention, Rodrigo Martins.

[EDIT]
I've been trying to get something from these sources:

[Support multi-seat](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/593493)

[Configuration file for setup1](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/73690792/lightdm.conf)

[LightDM.conf](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/77821044/lightdm.conf)

[Virtual terminal switching with multiseat setup and lightdm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74353/virtual-terminal-switching-with-a-multiseat-setup-and-lightdm)

[multiseat sample xorg.conf ati intel](http://pastebin.com/YeCsnmhy)

I figured out more or less how to setup lightdm.conf for multiseat, but the problem now stands at xorg.conf, looking at the fourth and fifth links I had some idea of how to do the configuration, but I don't know how to call my second screen, that is connected to the VGA output , in the Section when it asks for the 'Identifier', 'Screen' and 'Monitor', is it just to put screen1 and monitor1? vga and vga-monitor?

Can you help me with this?

Comment: The only reference I know of is here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX I have no experience with this uncommon setup.

Comment: Thanks, I already read that, but as far as I know that instructions are for GDM, not LightDM and the GDM you have to use is an older version, I don't want it.

Comment: Sorry that information was not helpful.

Comment: @RodrigoMartins - what lightdm.conf options have you tried from this bug report? https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/593493

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://askubuntu.com/questions/21860/simple-multi-seat/26583#26583

Comment: @fossfreedom - This is just what I'm trying to do, but I cannot really test my LightDM configurations until I have my xorg configured, I know how to basically modify the xorg configurations, but I don't know how to say to it start a layout using the screen attached to the VGA output. I'll update my question about it. Make your comment an answer and I will award the bounty to you.

Answer (score 9):

Multi-seat support for LightDM was discussed [during development](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/593493) and a fix has been released for Oneiric:

> Support multi-seat setup. This is (I think) when you run two sessions
>   on a single X server (with two displays/keyboards/mice).

The basic configuration of lightdm.conf is

```
[LightDM]
displays=display0 display1

[display0]
xserver=xserver0

[display1]
xserver=xserver1

[xserver0]
layout=layout0

[xserver1]
layout=layout1
```

The lead developer also gives this example in the report:

```
[LightDM]
xserver=default-xserver

[default-xserver]
command=/usr/bin/X -foo
config-file=/etc/X-foo.conf
layout=layout0
```

Thus for each video card you need to define an X-session (through xnest & xephir)

In the report a [specific example](http://netpatia.blogspot.com/2009/07/multiseat-with-nvidia-card.html) of a xorg.conf file should support for multiple nvidia displays.

In terms with running multiple X sessions from one video card this is [currently unsupported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/812170).

I hope this answer gives you some ideas to work through.