# multiple monitors, multiple workspaces, multiple mouse&keyboards

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces, multiple-workstations

I have three monitors,  three workspaces, and three mouses & keyboards, **and only 1 Linux machine.**

Can I attribute each monitor and mouse and keyboard to a specific workspace?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up a multiseat system?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86031/how-to-set-up-a-multiseat-system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a "multiseat X" configuration.

There's a page on Ubuntu Wiki about it: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX

Other links:

[How to set up a multiseat system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86031/how-to-set-up-a-multiseat-system)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19340/how-can-i-run-a-separate-x-session-on-a-different-physical-display