# Setting up multiseat the easy way on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: scripts, gdm, nvidia-geforce, multiseat

I have two monitors and want two users to be able to use my computer at the same time with different keyboards and mice.

I have an Nvidia GTX 970 Graphics card and Intel processor and integrated graphics in the motherboard.

I have been trying to understand the different tutorials but am unable to understand them.

I'm not able to edit all those config files and run those commands.

Is there an easy way like with a GUI or a script to set up multiseat in Ubuntu?

I'm using `GDM` and Gnome BTW.

Comment: Unfortunately the requests for multiseat seem less and less common and thus no easy to use graphical tools. The arch wiki is most up to date - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg_multiseat . The Debian and Ubuntu specific documentation seems older. https://wiki.debian.org/Multi_Seat_Debian_HOWTO and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX . Give it a read , take a deep breath, and ask more specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up a multiseat system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86031/how-to-set-up-a-multiseat-system)

Answer (score 2):

The different tutorials make multiseat more complicated than it has to be.  I wrote a GUI which simplifies the seat assignment process and called it EasySeats.

https://github.com/ezst036

You will need to change your display manager to LightDM.  The 3.x branch of GDM does not support multiseat to my knowledge.

Comment: Sorry? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/3.28.2-0ubuntu1.1 "
 It supports multiple seats and switching between multiple users."

Comment: It did not work at the time.  I apologize, I have not had time recently to come back and re-visit this.  However, I tested this using Ubuntu 18.10 and it works as expected with GDM.